# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' Hugging-Face transformers

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use Huggingface to transform stuff from English to Hindi.
This is the code snippet

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-hi")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-hi")
text = "Hello my friends! How are you doing today?"
tokenized_text = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch([text])

# Perform translation and decode the output
translation = model.generate(**tokenized_text)
translated_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translation, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]

# Print translated text
print(translated_text)
```

I am getting this error while trying to call the method generate on 'model'.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'.

I am running on transformer version 4.3.3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The model requires pytorch tensors and not a python list. Simply add `return_tensors='pt'` to [prepare_seq2seq](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/marian.html?highlight=prepare_seq#transformers.MarianTokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch):

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-hi")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-hi")
text = "Hello my friends! How are you doing today?"
tokenized_text = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch([text], return_tensors='pt')

# Perform translation and decode the output
translation = model.generate(**tokenized_text)
translated_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translation, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]

# Print translated text
print(translated_text)
```

Output:

```
आप आज कैसे कर रहे हैं?
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have the same problem and tried your solution but got another 'RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (522) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1'

Comment: Can you please open a separate question with a reproducible example? Your model is only able to handle up to 512 tokens but the text you provide consists of 522 tokens. You, therefore, need to split or truncate (depending on your task) your input to 512.